# How can I use only my custom models with social-auth-app-django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-socialauth, social-auth-app-django

How can I store people logged in or registered with social authentication only in the custom user model?

By default, whenever I use social auths, they are registered in User social auths in PYTHON SOCIAL AUTH on the Admin page, but I would like to remove this duplication with the custom user model.

This does not mean that I want those displays to disappear from the admin page, but rather that I want to optimize the database space.

Libraries I use are DRF, socil-auth-django and Djoser.

I want to keep only my custom user model. No other user model is needed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.